# How can I save Excel worksheets in a single workbook as workbooks with their data

Tags: python, python-3.x, pandas

How can I save Excel worksheets in a single workbook as workbooks with their data?
I've been able to load the workbook into python with:

```py
import pandas as pd
sheets = pd.read_excel('File.xlsx', sheet_name=None)
new_sheet=sheets.keys()
```

My issue is how to make the different sheets as data-frame using pandas with their name and save it in the same directory.

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

```
import pandas as pd

df=pd.read_excel(File.xlsx', sheet_name=None)
sheet_names=df.keys()

for sheet_name in sheet_names:
    sheet_name=pd.DataFrame(df[sheet_name].head())
    sheet_name.to_csv(str(sheet_name)+'.csv', index=False)
```

Note: Ensure your 'File.xlsx' is in the same directory as your code file.